# Using Greater Than In FQL Queries

Tags: error-handling, facebook-fql

Can anyone tell me why this works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql
?q=SELECT display_name FROM application WHERE app_id=0&access_token=...
```

(and returns 0 results, obviously)

but this doesn't:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql
?q=SELECT display_name FROM application WHERE app_id>=0&access_token=...
```

(HTTP 500)

The FQL pages on Facebook itself only ever give the simplest of queries - they never give samples of more complex queries involving strpos() and anything other than =.

I am aware of the need to work on an indexed column, but app_id is definitely one of those :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is indexable you still need to provide specific values for it. 
If you could provide vague ranges (e.g. '>0') it would defeat the restriction of requiring you to specify the target objects first, and filter later

Comment: OK, I understand. Shame - it makes it impossible to get what I hoped for as the only columns that are indexed all require you to return just one row (in the Application table, that would be a single app ID, a single namespace, or a single key).

Comment: You can use the `IN` keyword to pass an array of objects: `SELECT display_name FROM application WHERE app_id IN (TEST_ID_1, TEST_ID_2, ... TEST_ID_n)`